# Loading .so file in HTTPD Server

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, google-compute-engine

I have integrated the `ioncube` to `PHP`, `PHP` is showing correctly:

```
PHP -v

PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 11 2013 03:29:57)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
```

When running in the `httpd` server it is shows the following error:

```
Failed loading /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:
/usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:
cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

Extra Information:

Linux X86_64 Linux CentOS6 Google Compute Engine Instance.
It had two file ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so & ioncube_loader_lin_5.3_ts.so,
I have used the first one alone.

Comment: Have you ensured that `ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so` has the correct filesystem permissions?

Comment: I have given the permission as chmod 777 and verified

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue using the

it contains only zend_extension alone add zend_extension_ts

## vi /etc/php.ini

zend_extension=/usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
**zend_extension_ts=/usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3_ts.so**

Comment: zend_extension_ts does not exist as of PHP 5.3, so this is not the solution, but good news that the problem is resolved. You can also contact ioncu.be/S for guidance when you need it. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube

Comment: Thanks Nick. This will create any problem when we include _ts file. Without that it was not working. I found in one site they mention to add ts file in php.ini file

Comment: As mentioned, zend_extension_ts does not exist in PHP 5.3 or later (ref: docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). You should use the _ts Loader if PHP is built with thread safety. There was probably some other issue that went away at the same time.

Comment: I Nick just to be sure. In case of cloud it install only thread safe. I used yum install php httpd php-mysql php-gd in GCE with CentOS please let me if it will create any other problem. Thanks for guide us...

Comment: Sorry Krishnan but I didn't quite understand the query. Just ensure that you use the _ts Loader if your PHP install is thread safe, and the one without _ts if not. You should get errors when starting PHP or the web server software if there is a mismatch. You can check whether PHP is built with thread safety from a phpinfo page.

Comment: Thanks Nick, You are right, It says "Thread Safety" : "disable", But the application is still working good, if I remove that it is not running. I am not sure what was the case. May be the application is return in thread safe but the platform is not thread safe. But simple <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> page also did not work. What can I do now? As of now Application is working fine later I may get some problem. Just want to fix it right now.